# How to parse values from list into a function as separate values (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been attempting to parse variables from a list into a function separately. I don't know how to parse each value from the list into the `.format()` function. The solution is probably pretty obvious but I can't seem to find it. Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
variables = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

def format(variables):
    string = "{:^4}" * len(variables)

    #don't know how to do
    return string.format(variables_from_list)
```

Ideally, the code would work the same as below:

```
variables = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

def format(variables):
    string = "{:^4}" * len(variables)

    print(string.format("a", "b", "c", "d"))
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use "splat" arg unpacking: `.format(*variables)`

Comment: Please see the section starting "Another usage of the `*l` idiom is to unpack argument lists when calling a function." in the accepted answer of the linked question.

Comment: BTW, it's a good idea to avoid using `string` as a variable name because it's the name of a standard module.

Comment: This was just an example of the problem and not a sample of my code but thanks anyway.